# React Native, Objective C returning nil whit initWithBase64EncodedString

Tags: objective-c, react-native, image, base64

I'm trying to passe base64 images from react native to objective c so that I can retrieve image's data pixels with the help of openCV.

However, each base64 image return nil when using `initWithBase64EncodedString`.
I have tried multiple answer regarding this issue but none worked.

The Base64 comes from the result of ImagePicker in React Native

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({...})
```

here is the code used in Objective C :

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getImagePixels:(NSString *)imageAsBase64 callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
   NSUInteger paddedLength = imageAsBase64.length + ((4 - (imageAsBase64.length % 4)) % 4);
   NSString *correctBase64String = [imageAsBase64 stringByPaddingToLength:paddedLength withString:@"=" startingAtIndex:0];
   
   /* Here decodedData always nil */
   NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:correctBase64String options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
   
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedData];
   
   cv::Mat imageMat;
   cv::Mat imageMatRGBA;
   
   UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);
   
   cv::cvtColor(imageMat, imageMatRGBA, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGBA);
   cv::Mat Image8bit;
   imageMat.convertTo(Image8bit, CV_8UC1);

   unsigned char *pixelsChar = Image8bit.data;
   NSString *pixels = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)pixelsChar];
   
   callback(@[[NSNull null], pixels]);
}
```

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. debug your code. figure out where exactly it fails. inspect variables, attributes of instances, ...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz if it's not clear ... initWithBase64EncodedString always returning nil like said in the title. The function shows that the base64 string is corrected before being converted to NSData and why I need to do this in case any other solution is possible. Edited the question to keep the main problem.

Comment: ah, so it's failing before any OpenCV code is reached? I've untagged OpenCV. if you think OpenCV contributes to causing the issue, feel free to add the tag.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz This only leads to other discussion than resolving the issue. I'll leave it out.